# Automate a Keyboard Event that will Type in a Textbox

Tags: javascript

I need to automate a keypress. "That's not so hard," you might say, but listen, there's more. I don't want to just fire a `keydown` or `keypressed` event. I need to actually type a character into a textbox using JavaScript code.

Now, before you give me responses like `element.value = "Hooray!"` please realize this is not what I am looking for. The textbox I am trying to type in using code will not recognize my input if I change it using `.value` or `.innerText` or whatever. It would also be good to note that nothing about the textbox is able to be changed. I have to work with it how it currently is.

Thus, how can I type text into a textbox using JavaScript (no jQuery!) as if I typed it myself using a keyboard?

### Edit

The reason I say `.value` or `.innerText` won't work is because it doesn't trigger the textbox's text validation. So really what I'm asking is how I can 'type' something in programmatically so it will fire the text validation?

Comment: Please realize that you are providing ZERO concrete information about your problem. No code, no reason why the long list of things you say cannot be done cannot be done, no evidence of any attempt you already made... Nothing. You're almost asking for this to be closed. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example at the minimum

Comment: Does the javascript code need to run in the browser on the same page or would a solution where you automate opening a browser and simulating user input work, if so there are testing frameworks that could do that.

Comment: Also not saying its impossible but I think you are going to have a hard time with this because there is a lot security implemented in browsers to prevent code from doing things "as" a user.

Comment: Does the textbox honestly not change its value when you set it with something like `.value` or `.innerText`, or is that just not enough to move the experience forward? I ask because we had a similar case where we'd set a text field input programmatically, but that wouldn't trigger input validation. So we followed it up by `dispatchEvent()`ing a `paste` event; essentially pretending that the user pasted the text, which moved things along. Would something like that work?

Comment: @CemSchemel that is exactly what is happening here. Using `.value` I can add text to the field but it does not trigger input validation. I have looked into `dispatchEvent()` to no avail. However, I don't really know enough about how how the event stuff works (hence the question), so maybe your solution would work. Would you be able to post an answer with some example code?

Comment: Perhaps that solution will work then. Or at least worth a shot. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar case. It wasn't that the text field couldn't be set programmatically, but that setting it wouldn't trigger input validation. And the button to proceed wouldn't be enabled until/unless validation was complete.

We got around this not by programmatically typing every key, but rather by setting the value of the text field and then pretending that the user pasted it via an event. Like so:

```js
// Somehow get a reference to your text field in question
var textField = document.getElementById('myAwesomeField')

// Set the value to what you need
textField.value = 'Some valuable input'

// Programmatically create a 'paste' event
var pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste')

// Pretend that the user pasted, by having the textField dispatch the event
textField.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent)
```

Some relevant reading: [Clipboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent), [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). Getting an overview of events and eventing in general would also be helpful. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events) is one intro, though I'm sure more can be found. Once you get the hang of it, [here's a bunch of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) to whet your appetite about all the events you can trigger and/or react to.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Value with .value and after that you fire your validation function manually.

Comment: Could you please give some more information or an example. Your answer is not very clear